# Apache Ignite: can't insert data to persistent cache, because affinity for topology version is not initialized

Tags: c#, ignite

I am trying to insert data to persistent data region with thin .NET client and after I call PutAllAsync method ignite process is terminated with the following error:

`[15:45:09,616][SEVERE][exchange-worker-#66][] JVM will be halted immediately due to the failure: [failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_TERMINATION, err=class o.a.i.IgniteCheckedException: Affinity for topology version is not initialized [locNode=8fda194c-c82f-4d52-80b0-24ac1d7c8be7, grp=ignite-sys-cache, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=2], head=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=1], history=[AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=1, minorTopVer=1]]]]]`

Here is default-config.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <!--
        Alter configuration below as needed.
    -->
    <bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
      <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
      
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <property name="dataRegionConfigurations">
                <list>
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="name" value="data_persistent_region"/>
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                    </bean>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
      </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And here is an example of data insertion:

```
    var cacheConfiguration = new CacheClientConfiguration(key, cacheEntity);
    cacheConfiguration.CacheMode = CacheMode.Replicated;
    cacheConfiguration.DataRegionName = "data_persistent_region";
    _igniteClient.GetOrCreateCache<int, T>(cacheConfiguration)
        .PutAll(data.Select((x, i) => new KeyValuePair<int, T>(i, x)));
```

Tried to use "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" and "-DIGNITE_QUIET=false" options but it did not help.

PS. I am using Apache Ignite 2.10.0. If I disable region persistance everything works ok.

Answer (score 1):

Seems I figured out what was the problem: cache key contains not supported symbol ":" to create file with the same name.